# 403 Error when try to test Stripe CLI in windows

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

Hello I am trying to Test Stripe CLI on my Windows machine I have downloaded the stipe.exe and I have added it to the PATH. I read [Dcoumnet](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli) and but unfortunately when I trying to login with :

```
stripe login
```

I get 403 Error like this :

```
unexpected http status code: 403 We're sorry, but we're unable to serve your request.
```

I try also run the command in Powershell and I run both of cmd and powershell with adminstaration access but result is same any idea how can I fix this problem? Thank you so much

Update :
I try to use another method and this is the output I keep getting 403 :

```
C:\Users\Pourya\Downloads\stripe_1.19.1_windows_x86_64>stripe login --api-key sk_test_*********
unexpected http status code: 403 We're sorry, but we're unable to serve your request.

C:\Users\Pourya\Downloads\stripe_1.19.1_windows_x86_64>stripe login
unexpected http status code: 403 We're sorry, but we're unable to serve your request.

C:\Users\Pourya\Downloads\stripe_1.19.1_windows_x86_64>stripe login --interactive
Enter your API key:
Your API key is: sk_test_***********************************************************************************************BCtT
How would you like to identify this device in the Stripe Dashboard? [default: DESKTOP-7NICFBT]
> Done! The Stripe CLI is configured


C:\Users\Pourya\Downloads\stripe_1.19.1_windows_x86_64>stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/payment/webhook/
A newer version of the Stripe CLI is available, please update to: v1.19.2
[Fri, 26 Jan 2024 19:00:49 CET] FATAL Error while authenticating with Stripe: Authorization failed, status=403, body={"error":{"message":"We're sorry, but we're unable to serve your request.","request_log_url":"https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_fMX1fdY9a6XxCd?t=1706292063","type":"invalid_request_error"}}
```

Comment: I have same problem and I can't find a way to fix this issues

Comment: You should likely file an issue with on their github project with more details and any available nework diagnostics to reproduce this: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that wouldn't be working for you.  You could try one of the alternate CLI login approaches, such as `stripe login --api-key sk_test_<YOUR TEST KEY HERE>`

To use that, you'll need to go to Stripe through your browser, login there, and go get the API keys for your account.

You could also try using it in 'interactive mode', like this: `stripe login --interactive`

Comment: i test this but result was same

Comment: stripe login --interactive works but after that when i try to stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/webhook
i get 403 again

Comment: I bet this is related to 'security' or browser configuration. Do you perhaps have any unusual "firewall" systems installed?  I'm afraid I'm not very well versed in Windows details, so it's hard to speculate with more detail.  But, I imagine that a 403 means that the Stripe exe couldn't open some local ports or something like that and probably got an OS permission denied error of some kind.  "403" is similar to "401" but usually indicates a more systemic or programmatic problem.  So... think about firewalls and virus scanners and other permission related things on your machine

Comment: i am from iran and we cant use so many services becvause our nationality and i must use vpn maybe problem is this

Comment: You might raise this as an issue then and see whether there the app has support for setting the SOCKS proxy that should be used.  That would inform the stripe cli that it should use your VPN (I think).  I'll also look through the cli code a little and see if I can spot it.

Comment: You could try defining the environment variables: HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY in the shell where you are running stripe cli.  It looks to me like those settings should be respected and they might help you.  Check your VPN to get the proper proxy address value(s)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256691/discussion-between-pourya-mohamadi-and-bill-huneke).